# How to create Menu, sub-menu, sub-sub-menu using css and script inside jsp page which picks values from database?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsp, menu

I need some solution where i can pick data from database and display as menu--> sub-menu-->sub-sub-menu on jsp page

I have a database table which is as follows:

```
FIELD-NAME  DATATYPE

Heading         varchar2(50)
Level1         varchar2(50)
Level2         varchar2(50)
Level3         varchar2(50)
Level4         varchar2(50)
```

which has data respectively. Now i would like to pick that data based on selection and display as menu and sub-menu tab.

**For example:**

if i select in Heading lets say Menu-1 then it should display respective records of Menu-1 with a query `select level1 where heading='Menu-1'`.

I have gone through with some websites where the data is static. But i require that it displays dynamically inside jsp page using any script.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to create menu, submenu and sub-sub-menu in JSP page:

1. Select a design for your menu styling from http://onlinehtmltools.com/menu-generator/#sthash.lnae7EdD.dpbs
2. Copy that css code and html code in separate pages.
3. Create a database connection class and define methods in it to call specific column as

/*GET LEVEL1 REPORTS FROM HEADING*/

```
public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getReport_Area_level1(String val){

String sqlst="select DISTINCT LEVEL1 FROM MENU where heading='"+val+"'";

 /*connecting through appcontext.xml*/
    JdbcTemplate jt=new DbConnection().getJdbctemplate();
    SqlRowSet rs=jt.queryForRowSet(sqlst);


  HashMap<String, String> hm;
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> repList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
  System.out.println("Inside Database");
  while(rs.next())
  {  
          hm=new HashMap<String,String>();
          hm.put("0",rs.getString("LEVEL1") );
          System.out.println(hm.put("0",rs.getString("LEVEL1")));
          repList.add(hm);               
  }  
  return repList;
}
```

4. Now call that method which has query inside your JSP file

```
<ul id="menu_wrap1" class="Black">  
<%
    String val=request.getParameter("record");
    HttpSession hs=request.getSession();
    hs.setAttribute("level1", val);
    System.out.println("Value rep: "+val);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> repname = DbConnection.getReport_Area_level1(val);

    for (int i=0;i<repname.size();i++){ 

        String rep=repname.get(i).get("0");
        StringBuffer reportname=new StringBuffer(rep);
        System.out.println("Value rep inside for loop: "+reportname);
%>
<li class="button"><a href="#" id="<%=reportname%>" onclick="openPage1(this)"><%=reportname%></a></li>  

<%} %>
```

5.Save the file and execute. You can observe that respective data for respective field will be displayed. Apply same logic for any number of levels.